# Universe expansion data validation

Tags: expansion

I am not an expert, just a enthusiast, so if possible please keep explanation simple.
That said I have start reading about universe expansion and the idea seems to me revolutionary (the image of an infinite bigger universe that inflate).
So I am questioning how researcher validate that specific theory excluding other causes that IMHO would be more intuitive?

For example how they exclude that the expansion is not only a local effect (that's happening on ours patch of observable universe)?

Comment: Well, we can't exclude that, apart from using Occam's Razor: a theory that has uniform expansion in the observable universe but different expansion beyond the observable universe would be more complicated. The evidence of the expansion from the CMB radiation is *very* uniform, to better than 1 part in 100,000 over the entire surface of a sphere which is now ~46 billion light years in radius.

Comment: Intuitiveness is not a requirement for a theory to be accepted or we would not be using e.g. quantum theory or general relativity, which profoundly challenge our intuitions.  You kind of have to learn *new* intuitions to be comfortable with these theories.

Comment: The immense size of the Universe will always be challenging intuition and especially might render every theory about it unfalsifiable. I am afraid cosmology will always suffer of that. Unless something totally new or about closed universe emerges.